# OpenGL Frame Buffers

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I can't understand how render/frame buffers work in opengl. To use these buffers we start by writing some code like:

```
GLunit m_renderbuffer, m_framebuffer;
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &m_renderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_renderbuffer);
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &m_framebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                             GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                             GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
                             m_renderbuffer);
```

Then what? What functions are used to write to these buffers, and what functions are used to read from it & draw on the screen.

I checked a sample program but I never found m_renderbuffer or m_framebuffer used elsewhere. Also, the same for GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES. Looks like I missing the concept here.

Comment: You don't seem to be having any actual coding related problem. We're not here to teach/tell you how things work, your suppose to do that yourself. You should probably have a look at the [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page, before you post further questions!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting on a complex API. I would suggest you start with simple rendering to display first. There are many examples in the web, like [this](https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_gles20_vg.cpp)

Also, you are referring to an older spec, as GL_FRAMEBUFFER is no longer OES, and is part of the core specification itself in GLES2.0.